# php:5-apache mcrypt.h not found

Tags: docker, mcrypt, php-5.6

I work on some old project (Laravel 4.2) which use `mcrypt` and php5 and wanna run it on docker. Here is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:5-apache

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
    git \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zip \
    unzip &&\
    a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql 
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd 
RUN docker-php-ext-install pcntl  
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt
```

After run I get message:

> configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt.

I try to add `libmcrypt` under `apt-get install` in above file but I get:

> E: Unable to locate package libmcrypt

In similar way I try to add `php5-mcrypt` but I get:

> E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate

If I use (and combine with above) `FROM php:5-apache-jessie` and add line `RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php` before `RUN apt-get update &&\` i still get above errors.

Question: **How to solve this?**

Comment: *I wanna to use mcrypt in php.* Not to be that guy, but: no. You don't. `mcrypt` has pretty much been abandonware since the second it was released, and there's more than one reason it's been removed in PHP 7.

Comment: @Loek - I work on old project which use php5 and mcrypt - currently I have no choice (I update my question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of use `libmcrypt` or `php5-mcrypt` (below line `apt-get install -y \`) just use following library in dockerfile:

```
libmcrypt-dev \
```